# How to revert a change and then re add the change that has been added as a root user

Tags: git, root

I have a bit of a troublesome problem. Someone accidentally pushed to my gitlab page with some root files, and it caused a 500 encoding error for the commit data and the whole directory tree. I've had this happen before, and is what I usually due is just revert that change and tell them to re add and re commit everything only making sure everything as set as a normal user. Unfortunately, this person had a large commit that I doubt he could remake accurately.

I've already tried reverting the change, and then reverting my revert to see if that would work which didn't. So I'm out of ideas, and not really sure what to try next.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks, Joshua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch!  As a general rule I try to use only one user per repo (other users can clone it it and sync using `push` and `pull`).

If you revert your change and then make it again as a normal user, there is a risk that some funny file still remains, in fact some funny files will certainly still remain inside the hidden `.git` tree.  I would instead force everything to be owned by your main user.  Assuming you have such a "main" user for this repo you can try

```
  (become root)
  cd DA_REPO
  chown -R mainUser:herGroup .
```

This should set the ownership on all files in the working directory AND in the hidden `.git` directory.  I admit I am hazy if `-R` actually descends into hidden directories.  So if it doesn't work can also try an explicit

```
  chown -R mainUser:herGroup .git
```

**[Update]** Upon reading the original question, I see it talks about a "500 Encoding Error".  It don't know what that means, or how it comes about, but it sounds like you have a version of a file with some bad characters in  it.  Git shouldn't care about that, but your program might.  Find out what those files are and replace them with working ones.  Also can you give more Detail about the erors you get?

Comment: Thanks for the response, and that's a good idea, but I still can't seem to add the data after I've reverted it. All the files in my .git directory and the entire git folder are belonged to my user and part of my users group. I'm starting to think this couldn't be fixed locally, and would need to be fixed remotely... I'm not sure though.

Comment: I even tried creating a patch of the bad commit, and then starting on a fresh clone with your chown commands and then applying it. My thought process was the bad permissions wouldn't transfer through a patch. But, it did not work...

Comment: I just noticed I didn't understand the nature of your error.  Have a look at the update to my answer.

Comment: The only error that appears is when viewing the commit data, or the directory tree. And it's the "500 Encoding Error.". I thought the same thing as you did about the bad characters, but this has happened three or fours time now, and every time the person tells me they accidentally pushed root files or committed them. So I'm fairly certain it is a problem with putting the root files onto the git, because I also put translation files onto same git that contain characters from over 30 languages.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of someone elses error, but it's exactly how mines looks. https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/1536036/327567/3727fdd6-9b7a-11e2-9088-48d9c4d0967e.png

Comment: Is this a web application?  In HTTP error 500 means "Internal Server Error" which happens when something nasty (e.g. an uncaught exception) happens inside the server-side code.  In this case it is something to do with an encoding.  I suggest you find out what part of what program is having Trouble with the encoding of what text.

Comment: When you're right you're right. I wen't through all of the files, and it turns out one of them had a spanish ó in it's name causing this error. I removed it and things are fine now. Thanks for the help